# Format file Error "'bcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Tags: azure-sql-database, bcp

I want to create format file (.fmt) for SQL server for bulk insert from azure blob storage. I'm using the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK 'week3/inv-2017-01-19.csv',
   DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureInvoices',
   FORMAT = 'CSV',
   FORMATFILE='invoices.fmt',
   FORMATFILE_DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureInvoices'
   ) AS DataFile;
```

I used this command in my cmd :

```
bcp [cpdb-dev].dbo.mykiosk_temp format nul -c -f C:\Users\BB-Pa\BCP\mk_data.fmt -T
```

But it gives an error:

> "'bcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file."

Do I need to install bcp separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error suggests that, you have an issue with PATH in environment variable.

> "'bcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file."

You can resolve above error by setting correct path in environment variable settings.

`BCP_PATH  = ODI_HOME\oracledi\client\odi\bin\odi.conf` should be added in environment variable settings.

Refer - https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4140433/bcp-is-not-recognized-on-odi-12c